# How can I extract the latest IIS log entries into SQL as they come in

Tags: c#, iis, logging

I have a need to consume IIS logs and process the data in near real time. I'm looking for ideas on how to best go about this. Log Parser doesn't seem to offer any solutions that I have been able to find.

Specifically I am looking to extract the IP address, date, time, and referring URL and send them straight to a SQL table, but I don't want to extract log entries that I have already extracted. Doing a bulk insert at the end of the business day is easy, but not an option.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need all entries, including images, css, and the like, or do you just need to know which pages were visited?

Comment: I don't need all entries, only IP address of the user, date, time, and referring URL. All other entries should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Microsoft does not recommend IIS logging to a SQL Server table if the IIS computer is a busy server.

Sending logging data to a SQL Server database for a busy Web site consumes system resources. In this case, you may want import the IIS logs to a SQL database later.

If you still want to enable the IIS logging to a SQL server, I suggest you could refer to below article:

1.If IIS version is 6.0 or lower:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245243/how-to-configure-odbc-logging-in-iis

2.If IIS version is 7.0 or above:

http://nirav.extreme-advice.com/2013/07/29/configure-iis-8-0-log-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use **Lizard Log Parser** application for IIS logs and other logs like system logs or things like that.
[LogParserLizard](https://lizard-labs.com/default.aspx)